# On Azure AD how can get my domain back from cqearlyaccess.onmicrosoft.com?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-active-directory

When I try to verify my domain on Azure AD (after creating the TX record at my DNS provider) I get the following message (in red at the bottom of image):

[image]

This may have been done in error by Azure when I tried to make use of the early access feature of EOTP (Email one-time passcode) - other then that I don't see how my domain could have gotten into a different tenant I never had anything to do with.

I obviously don't have access to cqearlyaccess.onmicrosoft.com and so I am stuck!

Ideas?

Comment: please refer this document https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d5754d26-a208-4a39-bcee-b70175f3e862/this-domain-has-been-previously-configured-on-an-existing-azure-ad-or-office-365?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Thanks @ShrutiJoshi-MT but nothing there is helpful as I mentioned I don't have access to this domain, I never setup 365 and cqearlyaccess does not seem to be related to it.  Seems like something went wrong with the Azure machinery somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can take over an unmanaged directory as an administrator in Azure Active Directory and remove your domain and then add it to your Azure AD Tenant.

For Internal Admin Takeover :

1. Create a Power BI user account that uses the domain name for the organization.
2. Verify the confirmation mail from Power BI.
3. Sign in to Microsoft 365 Admin Center with the Power BI user account.
4. You will receive a message that instructs you to Become the Admin of the domain name that was already verified in the unmanaged organization. Select Yes, I want to be the admin.
5. Add the TXT record to prove that you own the domain name at your domain name registrar.
6. After verification is completed, you will be the global administrator of the Organization  in Microsoft 365.
7. You can now remove your Domain from Microsoft 365 and add it to your Azure AD Tenant.

**Reference** : [Admin takeover of an unmanaged directory - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-admin-takeover)